# Java Hibernate Oracle sessions never get closed

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I'm opening some Oracle sessions from a java-hibernate app. When I shutdown my java-hibernate application, the oracle sessions remain opened, even if the java process is not seen as running with `ps -fea | grep java`.

The problem is that this oracle sessions *never* die, they remain there and the only way to kill them is either manually kill oracle process, restart the oracle instance or restart the unix box where oracle resides.

My java/hibernate app *always* closes the session with a final statement in the source code, no matter what.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Is difficult to help you without more information, but I thing I can guess. When you open or close sessions using hibernate you probably dont open real oracle sessions. Hibernate may use a pool or control when open or not a real session. So, your problem is not close your java session after each statement but to correctly close and finish hibernate's pool or whatever before kill your app.

Please post more information so i dont have to guess :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
I use C3P0 as a connection manager. The settings used are pretty much standard ones, I only modify the number of connections and timeout: 

c3p0.initialPoolSize=30
c3p0.minPoolSize=30
c3p0.maxPoolSize=70
c3p0.acquireIncrement=1
# close pooled Connections that go unused for # more than half an hour
c3p0.maxIdleTime=1800

So, I really don't change much what C3P0 does. One interesting thing to mention is that my app is usually deployed with MySQL, and it always works properly, but Oracle at sometimes has an unexpected behavior.